# How to change hover panel position

Tags: search-results, css, display-template

I am using Search Results page and I would like to change the position of the hover panel.
The code is generated on the fly by SharePoint. I just want to change left: 823px; to **left: 400px;**

Here is the DIV generated by SharePoint.

```
<div class="ms-srch-hover-outerContainer" id="ctl00_ctl43_g_cb70b9a5_9e99_4a9f_ad75_19b16101f232_csr2_hover" style="left: 823px; top: 53.5px; width: 392px; display: block; visibility: visible;">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to override the element using some CSS. However, as the style is inside the HTML you would need to use the **!important** parameter to override the inline style.

```
.ms-srch-hover-outerContainer {
left:400px !Important;
}
```

Or you should be able to fix it with some jQuery.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".ms-srch-hover-outerContainer").css("left", "400px !important");
});
```

Be aware that there is some underlying script that checks the search results positions and add some pixels to **left** element to ensure that everything displays nicely.

Comment: works like a charm :) Thanks. I keep forgetting to use **!Important**